# Exporting subgraph (sideeffect) to json file and importing back in graph

Tags: json, groovy, graph-databases, titan, gremlin

I want to export subgraph to json file and import in other graph. I tried as follows:

```
gremlin> subGraph = g.V().has("name","john").outE("has").subgraph("subgraph").cap("subgraph").next()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:5]
```

now i have sub graph object then i used graphson to write this subgraph object directly to json file as follows:

```
subGraph.io(GraphSONIo.build()).writeGraph("/tmp/subgraph.json")
```

But i am getting error like this:

```
(was java.lang.IllegalStateException) (through reference chain: com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.relations.RelationIdentifier["inVertexId"])
```

what is problem ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have a TinkerGraph as your subgraph but that subgraph contains a Titan identifiers which GraphSON doesn't know how to natively process. You need to provide the Titan serializers to GraphSON so that it knows how to deal with the `RelationIdentifier`. You don't say what version of Titan you are using, but I think this approach works regardless of the version:

```
mapper = GraphSONMapper.build().
                        addCustomModule(TitanGraphSONModule.getInstance()).
                        create()
writer = GraphSONWriter.build().mapper(mapper).create()
os = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/subgraph.json")
writer.writeGraph(os, subgraph)
```

The more modern approach for JanusGraph would be:

```
sg.io('/tmp/sample.json').
     by(IO.registry, org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.io.graphson.JanusGraphSONModuleV2d0.getInstance()).
   write().iterate()
```

Comment: i am using Titan 1.0 and graph object is titan graph using `graph = TitanFactory.open("../conf/titan-cassandra.properties")` when created subgraph with above gremlin query it gives `TinkerGraph ` object??
so can we create subgraph as titan graph object?

Comment: i tried your code on gremlin it gives error for mapper object as `No such property: TitanGraphSONModule for class: groovysh_evaluate`

Comment: Yes, the subgraph is an in-memory TinkerGraph even though your primary graph is Titan. Typically, that makes a lot of sense as you don't usually want to persist a subgraph. I don't remember if you can subgraph to Titan in 1.0 - I think that was added as a feature of TinkerPop much later. As for your error, I think you might need to import that class to the console - you can find the package name here: https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/1.0.0/titan-core/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/titan/graphdb/tinkerpop/io/graphson/TitanGraphSONModule.java